# What operations are governed by manage permission type listed in ACL API documentation of Platform of Trust?

Tags: api, platform, platform-of-trust

The ACL docs lists four permission types, as seen in [API documentation](https://docs.oftrust.net/?shell#acl-v1-from_identity-target_identity)

```
"read": true,
"write": true,
"link": true,
"manage": true
```

what operations are governed by `manage`?

Answer (score 0):

Manage permission type is for allowing delete and permission grants.